# Response.AppendHeader("Refresh" does not work in my app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a Web Application using ASP.NET C#.

The idea is to display the contents of an error table and autorefresh every 5 minutes.

I have tried this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "3 ;URL=SYS_IFCError.aspx");
```

and this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "3");
```

Has this command been phased out or something?

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: are you trying update from an ajax callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the refresh header is not working the way you expected, I am suggesting you to try one of 2 other approaches.

Refreshing using HTML meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
```

Refreshing using JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 3000);
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" /> does nothing also

Comment: Try to return `<script>` tag with the code I gave you. It will be executed and your page will be refreshed in 3 seconds.

Comment: setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 3000); did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean a [META refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=http://example.com/">
```

Which is a HTML tag, it's not a HTTP header like what you're doing now.